# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

In my app I am checking to see whether a post has a picture or not.

For this I am using:

```
if pictures[string]? != nil {
    if var image: NSData? = pictures[string]? {
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: image!)
    }
}
```

However, it still comes up with the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I'm sure it is something easy to fix but I am quite new to this - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
if let imageData = pictures[string] {
    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Assuming that `string` is a valid key.

You are dealing with optionals, so conditionally unwrap each return object before using it.

Forced unwrapping is dangerous and should only be used when you are **absolutely** sure that an optional contains a value. Your imageData may not be in the correct format to create an image, but you are forcibly unwrapping it anyway. This is okay to do in Objective-C as it just means `nil` objects get passed around. Swift is not so tolerant.

Comment: Thanks :) Working now!

Answer (score 1):

It is the issue of swift when you forget to wrap optional values

Replace line `imageView.image = UIImage(data: image!)` 
with `imageView?.image = UIImage(data: image!)`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with this code

```
if(!placeholderColor.isEqual(nil))
 {
   self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder!, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeholderColor])
 }
```

and solved by this

```
if let placeColor = placeholderColor
 {
   self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder!, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeColor])
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First Double check the format of the base64 string. My string had the following format:  `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJAAAACQCAYAAADnRuK4AAAZDElEQVR42u1daWATZRp+JkfT+76g90ELtKUX5wICshREgYKCKAiCC4iCu+Iq6q6CoKuLF4Igl6jLDaKgiJwiN5SjQAulpTe97zY90qRJ9sc` but everthing before the the comma is not required. I got the code working by changing the format to:
`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJAAAACQCAYAAADnRuK4AAAZDElEQVR42u1daWATZRp+JkfT+76g90ELtKUX5wICshREgYKCKAiCC4iCu+Iq6q6CoKuLF4Igl6jLDaKgiJwiN5SjQAulpTe97zY90qRJ9sc`