# iOS Swift Assigning label text from variable known to contain value is throwing error

Tags: ios, swift

Entire project code (so far) is uploaded to https://github.com/mikeyj777/MyFavoriteMovie/tree/master/MyFavoriteMovies

I'm unsure where I'm deviating from the code in the "recipe" lecture. however, when the program is in the tableviewcell class (FavMovieCell.swift), running "configureCell" method, the following line

lblTitle.text = movieRecord.title

throws an error.

before executing the line, I confirmed that movieRecord.title is populated:

(lldb) po movieRecord.title

▿ Optional("Out of Africa")

- Some : "Out of Africa"

When the line is executed, here is the error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

it would seem the error is stating that movieRecord.title is unwrapped as nil.  However, I can see it has a value.

Any advice on what is causing this error, please let me know.

Here is the code for the tableviewcell class throwing the error:

```
class FavMovieCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imgMovie: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDescr: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblLink: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


}

func configureCell(movieRecord:FavMovie) {
    lblTitle.text = movieRecord.title
    lblDescr.text = movieRecord.descrWhyGood
    lblLink.text = movieRecord.linkImdb
    imgMovie.image = movieRecord.getImg()
}

}
```

Comment: did you check your outlets connected properly???

Comment: thanks!  how did I miss that?

Comment: glad it helps brother :)

Comment: @MichaelJames It seems from the console, Could not load the "howard the duck" image referenced from a nib.. Once check have u added that image to project

Comment: lblTitle?.text = movieRecord.title
        lblDescr?.text = movieRecord.descrWhyGood
        lblLink?.text = movieRecord.linkImdb
        imgMovie?.image = movieRecord.getImg()   Change the code like this and check, But i don't know the exact  reason

Comment: Once refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675490/unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-optional-value