# The page is not added to PDF, it gives an error "Optinal value"?

Tags: swift, pdf, uiimagepickercontroller, pdfkit, pdfpages

Good afternoon, I want to call a function in a button to add an image page to a document.Here in this method which provided below.

```
@IBAction func mergeButton(_ sender: Any) {
  
  
        let newDocument = PDFDocument()
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "image")
      
        let page = PDFPage(image: image!)
        
        newDocument.insert(page!, at: 0)
        newPDF.document = newDocument
      
    }
```

This is my entire code. I was going to upload the image via picker and then add it to the pdf document. Can anyone help me correct what is wrong? Below is my entire code

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,PDFViewDelegate {
  
    
    let pdf = PDFView()
    let newPDF = PDFView()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfImage: UIView!
    
   
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageGallery: UIImageView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      pdfImage.addSubview(pdf)
        mergeFile.addSubview(newPDF)
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foglio", withExtension: "pdf") else {
            return
        }
        
        
        guard let document = PDFDocument(url: url) else {return }
        
        pdf.document = document
        pdf.autoScales = true
        pdf.delegate = self
        newPDF.delegate = self
            
        
        
    }
  
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        pdf.frame = pdfImage.bounds
        pdf.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        newPDF.frame = mergeFile.bounds
        newPDF.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
    }

   
    @IBOutlet weak var mergeFile: UIView!
    
    
    @IBAction func mergeButton(_ sender: Any) {
  
  
        let newDocument = PDFDocument()
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "image")
      
        let page = PDFPage(image: image!)
        
        newDocument.insert(page!, at: 0)
        newPDF.document = newDocument
      
    }
    
    @IBAction func ImageUpdate(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
     private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as? UIImage {
           
            imageGallery.image = image

        }
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


     func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

  

   
}
```

Comment: can you point out at which line you got error in your code?

Comment: line "let page = PDFPage(image: image!)" Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I don't think there is a systemName called "image", so `let image = UIImage(systemName: "image")` returns nil. So when you use `image!` it crashes your app.

Comment: Are you sure there is an image with the name "image" present in the Asset otherwise it doesn't return nil and it crashes your app.

Comment: So, how can I fix the error? can you show an example

Comment: yes image name "image"

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675490/unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-optional-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Comment: Silent function is not an error and nothing changes. bottom code function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
    let newDocument = PDFDocument()
    if let image = UIImage(named: "image"),
       let page = PDFPage(image: image) {
        newDocument.insert(page, at: 0)
        newPDF.document = newDocument
    }
```

Comment: Silent function is not an error and nothing changes.

Comment: does your "image" in your `Assets.xcassets` directory has an extension? If yes, include the extension in `UIImage(named: "image.png")`

Comment: how to turn on? i added at the end .png to the name image assets.xcassets

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how to turn on?".

Comment: If yes, include the extension in UIImage(named: "image.png")

Comment: Using my code, can you try: `if let image = UIImage(systemName: "globe"), ...` as a test.

Comment: Found a mistake someone can change. It is necessary to replace UIImage(systemNamed: "image") ->UIImage(named: "image")

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: No, but you suggested where the error could be. You can above, I indicated what the reason was, change your answer. For my fix.As you wrote, it does not go and does not see the Object

Comment: my answer shows clearly to use `UIImage(named: "image")`, like you said this is the reason. My answer does not work for you?

Comment: Yes, I tried and the action in brackets does not go line if let image ..... newPdf.document = newDocument  ....The process went, but the picture was not found

Comment: I'm confused here. You say `UIImage(systemNamed: "image")` works but  `UIImage(named: "image")` does not work.

Comment: You misunderstood, I meant your action in such brackets does not find { ....... } . But with UIImage But with the picture there was a clue how to write it down. Send me a message on telegram @bravobet999 please help

Comment: if the code in `{...}` is not done, it is because `UIImage(named: "image")` returns nil. This means it cannot find "image" in your `Assets.xcassets` directory of your Xcode project. I do not do telegram.